# Link to a text element within an SVG from a separate HTML page

Tags: html, url, svg

Is it possible to create a hyperlink to (not from) part of an SVG file? Specifically, I'd like to either zoom to or highlight a specific text element within an SVG file, but doing so from a separate HTML file.

I will have pre-knowledge of the SVG text element's id and position.

I've tried URLs like below without success, referencing either/both the text elements Id as well as text fragments:

- ../example.svg#obj-text-4005
- ../example.svg#:~:text=abc

(update, sorry if I've omitted important details)

The SVGs are part of a collection I have generated myself, and I was hoping (maybe naively) that I could create an unrelated HTML page that would act as an "index" of keywords. This "unrelated HTML page" could simply be a list of URLs, each to a different text element within a given SVG.

Whether the SVG can be referenced/opened directly, or if/how it needs to be part of its own HTML page, is an open and unknown question to me. It's a matter of whatever works and is most practical.

Comment: Maybe add JS to your page with SVG that reads the URI and changes the SVG

Comment: To help it is important to know how the SVG is related to the HTML page. Is is just a link from one to the other, is the SVG referenced in at img tag or is it inline in the HTML? Share your code.

Comment: Sorry if I missed important details. I've given additional context in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of things that solved my problem.

1. Target a `<view>` tag: I didn't appreciate that the target within an SVG needed to be a `<view>` tag. As I am authoring the specific SVG I'm trying to link to, I can create those `<view>` tags as required. e.g.,

   - `<view id="obj-text-4005" viewBox="1800 900 200 200"/>`
   - Now the URL works as I intended: *./example.svg#obj-text-4005*
2. Use `#svgView()`: perhaps cooler than the first option was my discovery of the `#svgView()` target attribute. It allows a view box to be defined within the URL, examples below:

   - Maintain aspect ratio: *./example.svg#svgView(viewBox(1800,900,200,200))*
   - Don't maintain aspect ratio: *./example.svg#svgView(viewBox(1800,900,200,200);preserveAspectRatio(none))*

References below:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#ViewElementViewTargetAttribute
- https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/view